# WPF - Unit testing a custom markup extension

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, markup-extensions

how would you recommend unit testing a custom markup extension in WPF?  Presumably, I need to create an instance of my markup extension and call the ProvideValue method. However, this requires an IServiceProvider, which contains an IProvideValueTarget service.  How would I generate this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much do you rely on the IServiceProvider in the implementation of the MarkupExtension? Perhaps you could just mock it out?

I've done this to test MarkupExtensions, but then I haven't relied on the IServiceProvider, so it's been fairly trivial to test...